# component object has no attribute 'ln_solver'

Tags: python

I'm building a large new OpenMDAO component. When I run it, OpenMDAO crashes with `AttributeError: 'myNewComponent' object has no attribute 'ln_solver'` during the setup stage. What does this message mean?

```
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import Group, Component, Problem, IndepVarComp, ParallelGroup
from openmdao.api import ScipyOptimizer
from openmdao.core.mpi_wrap import MPI
if MPI: 
    from openmdao.core.petsc_impl import PetscImpl as impl
else:
    from openmdao.api import BasicImpl as impl

class WindSEComp(Component):
    def __init__(self, nTurbs, rotor_diameter):

        super(WindSEComp, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('turbineX', val=np.ones(nTurbs), units='m', desc='x positions of turbines in original ref. frame')
        self.add_output('AEP', shape=1)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        mx_opt = params['turbineX']
        unknowns['AEP'] = np.sum(mx_opt)

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        mx_opt = params['turbineX']
        J = {}
        J['AEP', 'turbineX'] = 3 * mx_opt
        return J


prob = Problem(impl=impl, root=WindSEComp(nTurbs=4, rotor_diameter=126.0))
#prob.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
#prob.driver.add_desvar('turbineX')
#prob.driver.add_objective('AEP')

prob.setup()
prob.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a component like a group: these are not the same. You want to do something like this:

```
top = Problem()
root = top.root = Group()
root.add('g', WindSEComp(nTurbs=4, rotor_diameter=126.0))
top.setup()
top.run()
```